# get parts of string using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, string

I have one string as

```
/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/
```

I want to get two separate variables which will contain port and IP

like. `192.168.0.1` and `8080`

as I know /ip/ and /port/ will be there always I got Ip as follows,

```
expr /ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/ : '/ip/\(.*\)/port/'
```

this will output **`192.168.0.1`**
just don't know how to get port, 
I tried similar command as,

```
expr /ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/ : '/port/\(.*\)/'
```

but it doesn't give port .. how to get port also.

Comment: Change the end of line like `'.*/port/\(.*\)/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk:

`awk -F\/ '{print $2"="$3, $4"="$5}' input_file`

with either an input file or just line by line.

Comment: Thank you :). I have edited question.. I only want 192.168.1.1 . not ip=192.168.1.1.

Comment: Then remove the $2"=" and the $4"=" so it just prints the ip value and port value

Comment: Same with `grep` `grep -o "[0-9.]\+" <<< /ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/`

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use **`cut`** as follows:

```
cut -d '/' -f 3,5
```

Example:

```
$ echo '/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/' | cut -d '/' -f 3,5
192.168.0.1/8080
```

This will cut with delimiter `/` and prints 3rd and 5th fields.

Or following may you want:

```
$ echo ip=`cut -d '/' -f 3 input_file` port=`cut -d '/' -f 5 input_file`
ip=192.168.0.1 port=8080
```

Answer (score 4):

Another pure bash way using arrays:

```
$ s="/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/"        # initial string
$ a=(${s//// })                         # substitute / with " " and make array
$ echo ${a[1]}                          # Array index 1 (zero-based indexing)
192.168.0.1
$ echo ${a[3]}                          # Array index 3 (zero-based indexing)
8080
$
```

Or similar to the above, but using IFS instead of parameter expansion to split the string:

```
$ OLDIFS="$IFS"                         # save IFS
$ IFS="/"                               # temporarily set IFS 
$ a=($s)                                # make array from string, splitting on "/"
$ IFS="$OLDIFS"                         # restore IFS
$ echo "${a[2]}"                        # Array index 2
192.168.0.1
$ echo "${a[4]}"                        # Array index 4
8080
$
```

Note this method is potentially more general than the other two in this answer in that it should still work if the fields of interest contain whitespace.

---

Or using positional parameters:

```
$ s="/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/"        # initial string
$ set -- ${s//// }                      # substitute / with " " and assign params
$ echo $2                               # Param 2
192.168.0.1
$ echo $4                               # Param 4
8080
$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expr /ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/ : '.*/port/\(.*\)/'
```

`.*` matches the initial part of the string before `/port`

Comment: yes it works. thanks. don't know Regex that much :(

Answer (score 3):

With `bash`

```
s=/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/
IFS=/ read -r _ _ ip _ port <<<"$s"
echo "$ip"
192.168.0.1
echo "$port"
8080
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way

```
$ cut -d '/' -f 3,5 <<< "/ip/192.168.0.1/port/8080/"|tr -s '/' ' '
192.168.0.1 8080
```

Comment: "I want to get two separate variables ..."

Comment: Ops, missed it. In that case @DigitalTrauma answers should be the appropriate one.